# Textbox automatically get filled inside ng-form tag using angularjs

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-form

when user select textbox option, it will dynamically generate textbox and append it to the div otc-dynamic..now the problem is if i select more than one time textbox option and type in any one of the textbox all the textbox get starts filling up....i want to stop that..thnx in advance
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nilamsavani/n2nqkcn8/

```js
app.directive("otcDynamic", function ($compile) {
            var i = 1;
            return {
                link: function ($scope, $element) {
                    $scope.add = function () {
                        $scope.myVar = false;
                        if ($scope.filter.country == 'TextBox') {
                            
                            str = "<ng-form name='form'><span>Text: </span><input type='text' placeholder='Answer' id='" + i + "' ng-model='txt' name='input'  required /><div class='validation_error' data-ng-show='form.input.$error.required' style='color: red'>Can't be empty.</div></ng-form>"
                           
                        } else if ($scope.filter.country == 'Number') {
                            str = "<ng-form name='form1'><span>Number: </span><input type='number' placeholder='Answer' ng-model='num' required ng-minlength='3' name='inumber' id='" + i + "'/><div class='validation_error' data-ng-show='form1.inumber.$error.required' style='color: red'>Number required.</div></ng-form>"
                           
                        } else if ($scope.filter.country == 'Select') {
                        }
                        alert(str);
                        el = $compile(str)($scope);
                        $element.parent().append(el);
                        
                        i++;
                    }  
                }
               
            }
        });
```

```html
<div ng-controller="mainController">
        <form name="myForm" novalidate>
           <%-- {{ message }}--%>
            <div otc-dynamic></div>
            <select ng-model="filter.country" ng-change="add()">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="TextBox">TextBox</option>
                <option value="Number">Number</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" ng-hide='myVar' value="Submit" ng-click="check()" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i don't have reputation to make comment, Your are generating text fields and number filed more 
   than once with same **ng-model** name so it's sharing the same **scope** so it's generating with same 
   value has previous text fields.

Comment: i have rename the ng-model='txtmodel" + i + "'.. now it allows me two enter different values in two texboxes but when i generate 2nd textbox, my 1st textbox has valid state still the error message is shown on my 1st textbox also

Comment: i have to also set form name as <ng-form name='form" + i + "'>....updated js fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/nilamsavani/n2nqkcn8/1/